# unresolved externals LNK2019 issue

Tags: c++

Trying to weave through the jungle and create some code in a existing SDK.
The kit came with a VC++ version 9 project file (VS2008)

I am using VC2012 Express and have imported in successfully.

I need to update some code in a build using a preprocessor macro "_ENABLE_MY_CUSTOM_DEVICE_SUPPORT"

When I build the file without this macro all is fine, but when I  build with macro unresolved external symbol error appears hence issues with the code within that area.

the error i am getting is

```
"Error  10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cMyCustomDevice::cMyCustomDevice(unsigned int)" (??0cMyCustomDevice@@QEAA@I@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cHapticDeviceHandler::update(void)" (?update@cHapticDeviceHandler@@QEAAXXZ)  E:\Programs (PE)\chai3d-2.0.0\examples\msvc9\01-devices\chai3d-debug.lib(CHapticDeviceHandler.obj)  01-devices"
```

OK so from what I understand its saying that it can't find the implementation of the prototype
`cMyCustomDevice::cMyCustomDevice(unsigned int)`

in the cpp source. But it is there I have a feeling i'm missing something simple, I know this might not be enough information but any thoughts or further questioning what I have done will  hopefully come to a solution.

Comment: What is the definition of the macro?

Comment: No, it can't find the code for the constructor in the linked library.  If you are sure that you are linking correctly then do suspect that _ENABLE_MY_CUSTOM_DEVICE_SUPPORT really means "_TODO_IN_VERSION_2".  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy thx guys just realised my issue had space in linker options between filename and postfix. All working just couldn't see space that well